# Why isn't this variable visible?

Tags: python, scope

O.K., I'm coming from Perl to Python and I don't have much experience in Python so this may seem rather obvious to everyone who's more experienced with Python.

Anyway, I'm simply loading a configuration file and then, as a self-test, printing the values that are loaded.  The code is below:

```
#!/home/y/bin/python2.7
import logging
import sys
import datetime
import yaml

def main(self):
    #initialize the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(self.granularity)
    log_fh = logging.FileHandler(filename='/home/logs/pipelineTest/pipelineTest' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M')  + '.log', mode='w')
    logger.addHandler(log_fh)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-6s: %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    log_fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    #read configuration file
    if sys.argv[1]:
        ymlFH = open(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        ymFH = open('/home/conf/pipelineTest/runPipeline.yml')

    confDict = yaml.load(ymlFH)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #self-test code
    for key, value in confDict.iteritems():
      print 'Key is: ' + key + '\n'
      print 'value is: ' + confDict[key] + '\n'
```

The error I'm encountering is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runPipeline.py", line 30, in <module>
    for key, value in confDict.iteritems():
NameError: name 'confDict' is not defined
```

Which I'm interpreting as the name "confDict" has gone out of scope.  I don't understand why it's gone out of scope.

Comment: This actually isn't so much of a python specific problem as you might think. Even in perl you have to call the function (or sub) to execute code. That being said, scope in perl should be the same concept if you are not using the super scary "non strict mode"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `main()` function has it's own scope - not only that, but you are never calling it.

I would suggest you return `confDict` from your function, and then do `confDict = main()` in your running block - or, if you are not going to use your `main()` function in more than one place, just put it straight down, don't bother with the function.

Comment: Thanks jdi, just managed to type the wrong word there, good sign.

Comment: I originally had the main function in there because the example I was working from for setting up a logger used it.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `confDict` is defined inside the function `main()`, so it is local to that function.  (By the way, you don't even call `main()`.)

You probably want to move the for loop from the end of the script to the end of the `main()` function, and call `main()` at the end of the script instead.

Answer (score 0):

confDict is local to main, and in python, function defenitions are indent dependant. So the function scope is over when you try to access it inside the if statement because main has already ended. (See indent)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `confDict` went out of scope, it never went **into** scope.

```
import ...

def main(self):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #self-test code
    for key, value in confDict.iteritems():
      print 'Key is: ' + key + '\n'
      print 'value is: ' + confDict[key] + '\n'
```

At the point of that `if __name__ == ...`, you have imported a bunch of names, and defined a function called `main`. The variable `condDict` has never been defined. I do not know of any language where analogous code would define `condDict`, regardless of what is filling in the `...` in `main`.

If you **call** `main`, it will create a variable called `confDict`. However that name will be local to that particular invocation of `main`, so you can't use it outside the function meaningfully (imagine you could; `main` could be called many times, and produce many values of `confDict`; which one would be meant when you refer to `confDict` outside `main`?).

I suggest you work through some Python tutorials. If you're already familiar with programming in general (i.e. Perl) then you'll blaze through them, but they'll clarify all these basic foundational issues so you can concentrate on coding.

---

As an aside, `self` as the argument to `main` makes no sense. Either remove it and have `def main():` or use `def main(args)` instead of pulling them out of `sys.argv` within `main` (my preference is for the latter).